# Converting unsigned char array to int

Tags: c++, arrays, casting

I'd like to convert my unsigned char array to a number. There is no problem with displaying my variable e.g. using ("session: %d ", session) pattern where session is my unsigned char array, I'm getting the value like "session: 1663616616" but I'dont know how to convert the session table to integer.
In other words, I'd like to cast(?) somehow the table to a single integer to have this "1663616616" in it. 
I'd be really thankful for the help.

Comment: more details please...! like code/whats your efforts/examples...etc

Comment: Please show a complete example of what you want to do, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please show the contents of the array.

Comment: The answer might be different for C vs. C++. Please tag only the language you are compiling with to get answers that are better for that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `session` is a `char` array, then `sprintf ("session: %d ", session)` evokes Undefined Behavior because `%d` means "`session` is an integer"

You should be doing `sprintf ("session: %s", session)` instead, but make sure `session` is a NULL-terminated string.

Comment: `sprintf` but i not see this in OP's Q.But there `("session: %d ", session)` and it looks me  printf.

Comment: @Jayesh:  Sorry, what?

Answer (score 5):

Use either C++ function `std::stoi` declared in header `<string>` or C functions `strtol` or `atoi` declared in C++ header `<cstdlib>` or C header `<stdlib.h>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    unsigned char session[] = "1663616616";
    int n = std::stoi( reinterpret_cast<char( & )[sizeof(session)]>( session ) );

    std::cout << "n = " << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
n = 1663616616
```

Or

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{

    unsigned char session[] = "1663616616";
    int n = atoi( session );

    printf( "n = %d\n", n );

    return 0;
}
```

In C++ the equivalent code will look as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{
    unsigned char session[] = "1663616616";
    int n = std::atoi( reinterpret_cast<char( & )[sizeof(session)]>( session ) );

    std::cout << "n = " << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or you may use a more simple casting

```
    int n = std::atoi( ( char * ) session );
```

Comment: It looks like a solution but while trying to compile I'm gettin:jni/stream.hpp:181:11: error: 'stoi' is not a member of 'std'
   int i = std::stoi( reinterpret_cast<char( & )[sizeof(session)]>( session ) );
           ^

Comment: @sliwkacz  This function is appeared in C++ 2011. If your compiler does not support it then use C functions atoi or strtol. See my updated post.

Comment: still doesn't work: note: initializing argument 1 of 'int atoi(const char*)'
 extern int atoi(const char*) __purefunc;

Comment: and the other output:jni/stream.hpp:182:25: error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned char*' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
   int i = atoi( session );

Comment: @sliwkacz See my updated post with one more example.

Comment: @sliwkacz  All examples of program are compiled fine.

Comment: actually, I'm still facing the same issue. the third one compiles fine but the value of the integer is 0

Comment: @Vtik It means that the array can't be converted to a number. Check the sequence of characters to be converted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **boost/lexical_cast**

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const char* str = "123456";
    int a = boost::lexical_cast<int>(str);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This will handled all possible integers (negative).

If the numbers are constrain maybe you like do it by hand (this code only work for positive numbers, for negative more logic is need), recommended use *lexical cast*:

```
long end = strlen(str);
int b = 0;
for (long idx = 0; idx < end; idx++) {
  b = (b * 10) + (str[idx] - '0');
}
std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

Comment: he said "I'd like to convert my unsigned char array to a number" not const char* ...